# Unusual spaces in html

Tags: html, list

I have used space characters in html to give regular spaces in my text but interestingly some text is still does not have regular spaces. Please have a look,

```
<ul style="margin-left:40px;background-color:#6CF ;padding-left:20px;padding-right:10px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px; font-size:12px;" >
<li>CS-103  &nbsp;&nbsp; Programming Languages</li>
<li>EL-133  &nbsp;&nbsp; Electronics-I</li>
<li>MT-111  &nbsp;&nbsp; Calculus</li>
<li>CY-105  &nbsp;&nbsp; Applied Chemistry</li>
<li>PH-121  &nbsp;&nbsp; Applied Physics</li>
<li>HS-105  &nbsp;&nbsp; Pakistan Studies | HS-127 Pakistan Studies(for Foreigners)</li>
</ul>
```

Here is how it looks,

CS-103     Programming Languages

EL-133     Electronics-I

MT-111     Calculus

CY-105     Applied Chemistry

PH-121     Applied Physics

HS-105     Pakistan Studies | HS-127 Pakistan Studies(for Foreigners)

Please help out to make all list element look same. Thanks

Comment: I see several answer below which are correct and provide a few different options for you. When your problem is solved, you should accept one of the answers. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for that. I am a little confused which one to select.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text does have regular spaces.  The problem is that the font you use is not fixed width, and the length of the course type/number is throwing it off.

Use a table for stuff like that.

Comment: At first I was like *"woah, a table?!"* But then I was like *"oh yeah, that's kind of OK"*

Comment: But still, a definition list is probably [the way to go](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12709777/1081234)

Comment: @o.v., Definition list is definitely an option.  I think it could go either way.  Personally, I would lean towards a table, but I think both are valid in this case.

Comment: Technicality: The text has both regular spaces and no-break spaces; the latter are denoted by `&nbsp;`. Using a table is the obvious and best solution, but if it must be a list for some reason, then it would suffice to set the codes in monospace font, e.g. `<code>CS-103</code>`.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on its semantic value, you could also use a definition list.

HTML:

```
<dl>
    <dt>CS-103</dt>
        <dd>Programming Languages</dd>
    <dt>EL-133</dt>
        <dd>Electronics-I</dd>
    <dt>MT-111</dt>
        <dd>Calculus</dd>
    <dt>CY-105</dt>
        <dd>Applied Chemistry</dd>
    <dt>PH-121</dt>
        <dd>Applied Physics</dd>
    <dt>HS-105</dt>
        <dd>Pakistan Studies | HS-127 Pakistan Studies (for Foreigners)</dd>
</dl>​
```

CSS:

```
dl {
    overflow: hidden;
    }

dt {
    float: left;
    width: 80px
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SVdTt/

Comment: +1 for the 1 minute you've beaten me by. Seriously though, I'm glad to see the trend of `dl` becoming better recognized

Answer (score 3):

Brad's feedback about inconsistent spacing when using non-monotype fonts is correct (and there is no `\t` symbol to use for tabulation in html), however it may be more appropriate to use a [definition list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html) here with some styling applied.

Semantics fit perfectly (a *term name* `dt` followed by its *description* `dd`):

```
<dl>
  <dt>CS-103</dt><dd>Programming Languages</dd>
  <dt>EL-133</dt><dd>Electronics-I</dd>
  ...
</dl>​
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/WDVeP/)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to choose a monospaced font for them to look the same if I understand correctly.